# sap UI5 Avatar icon issue

Tags: sapui5

Attaching Image.[image]
I'm using Avatar Icon and based on state i'm trying to change the color and the value.
But it's limited to "Accent 1-10" and unable to place any other color, how to put other colors like yellow, white and black etc? Also how to delete icon if string is null.

```
<Avatar id="idAvatar" initials="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatNumeric'}" displaySize="XS"
                                                    backgroundColor="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatIconColor'}"/>
```

formatter code and how can i'm getting error if i use 'yellow' in place of Accent8 etc. Please suggest.

```
formatIconColor: function (bms) {
        debugger;
        switch (bms) {
        case "5.0":
            return "Accent8";
            break;
        case "4.0":
            return "Accent1";
            break;
        case "3.0":
            return "Accent3";
            break;
        case "2.0":
            return "Accent2";
            break;
            case "1.0":
            return "Accent2";
            break;
            case "":
            return "Accent10";
            break;

        }
    },
```

As, i'm using custom list, how i can i remove icon from the List item which does not contain value.
by looping through the List on update finished(), how can i remove only icon (highlighted in the above image)and i want other elements to be present as it is: means not to delete entire item and only to delete icon element.

```
formatNumeric: function (bms) {
    debugger;
        switch (bms) {
        case "5.0":
            return "A";
            break;
        case "4.0":
            return "B";
            break;
        case "3.0":
            return "C";
            break;
        case "2.0":
            return "D";
            break;
            case "1.0":
            return "E";
            break;
            case "":
            return "O";
            break;

        }
    },
```

I'm using custom list item.

```
<VBox>
                <List id="sonarRepId" items="{ path: 'sonarMetrics>/measures' }" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
                    <items>
                        <CustomListItem id="idSonarList">
                            <FlexBox id="idFlex" alignItems="Start" justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" height="88px">
                                <items>
                                    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                        <!--<ObjectIdentifier title="{sonarReport>value}"/>-->
                                        <Link text="{sonarMetrics>value}" press="handlePress" class="sonarsapMLnk"/>
                                        <HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
                                            <core:Icon size="2rem" class="sonarsapMObjLIcon" src="{sonarMetrics>imageL}"/>
                                            <Label text="{sonarMetrics>name}" class="sapUiTinyMarginBegin"/>
                                        </HBox>
                                        <layoutData>
                                            <FlexItemData growFactor="2"/>
                                        </layoutData>
                                    </VBox>
                                    <HBox id="idHbox" class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                        <items>
                                            <HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginTop">
                                                <Link id="idLinkState" text="{sonarMetrics>state}" press="stateHandlePress" class="sapUiTinyMarginEnd"/>
                                                <Avatar id="idAvatar" initials="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatNumeric'}" displaySize="XS"
                                                    backgroundColor="{parts : [ 'sonarMetrics>state_value'], formatter: '.formatter.formatIconColor'}"/>
                                            </HBox>
                                        </items>
                                    </HBox>
                                </items>
                            </FlexBox>
                        </CustomListItem>
                    </items>
                </List>
            </VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In formatter function, you will have the control in your "this" reference. You can use "this" to hide your control, add a new colour and setBackgroundColor.

Formatter -

```
formatNumeric: function (bms) {
        switch (bms) {
        case "5.0":
            this.setBackgroundColor("Accent8");
            return "A";
        case "4.0":
            this.setBackgroundColor("Accent10");
            return "B";
        case "3.0":
            this.setBackgroundColor("Accent6");
            return "C";
        case "2.0":
            this.setBackgroundColor("Accent5");
            return "D";
        case "1.0":
            this.addStyleClass("yellow");
            return "E";
        case "":
        default:
            this.addStyleClass("hidden");
            return "O";
        }
    },
```

CSS -

```
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Alternative and a better approach to hide the control will be using Expression Binding

```
<VBox items="{oMasterModel>/items}">
    <Avatar visible="{= !!${oMasterModel>state_value}}"
            initials="{parts : [ 'oMasterModel>state_value'], formatter: 'com.TestIconTabBinding.util.formatter.formatNumeric'}" displaySize="XS"/>
</VBox>
```